# Converting Word doc to tiff

Tags: automation, ms-word, 64-bit, ms-office, win64

I run Word 2003 in unattended process to convert a word doc file into a tiff. Word is configured to print to Microsoft Office Document Image driver and then pick up the generated file. It works fine on a 32 bit OS.

Now we need to migrate this app on a 64 bit OS and it looks like there is no such driver in the Office 2003 installation on a 64 bit box.

So my question is What can I use instead of it on a 64 bit box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [XPS Printer driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145058(VS.85).aspx) and then convert the resultant PNG / JPEG to Tiff using some other image conversion package.  As far as I can tell from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162740(VS.85).aspx) it only supports PNG and JPEG.